# upload files to multiple web servers w/ Team Foundation Server or Visual Studio 2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010, tfs

Is there a way to copy changed files from TFS to multiple live web servers?

We used to use Unleash-It, but I'm guessing there's at least an add-on for VS2010 if there isn't something in TFS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at [Web Deploy](http://www.iis.net/download/WebDeploy).

Comment: What if they are using IIS Shared Configuration where Web Deploy doesn't work?